# How to dynamically create an object when looping an array?

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically create an object with key value pairs from an array of object. How can this be done?

```
const arr= [
  {key: 'a', value: '1'},
  {key: 'b', value: '2'},
  {key: 'c', value: '3'},
];
```

The result should look like this:

```
const obj = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
  c: '3',
};
```

Comment: That's easily done with a loop or `.reduce()`. So what have you tried so far and what problems did you have with it?

Comment: Use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [the square brackets syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Accessing_properties) to set the properties of the new object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for that.

The `agg` is an aggregator which aggregate our final result.

The `item` is representing each element in the array.

```js
const arr= [
  {key: 'a', value: '1'},
  {key: 'b', value: '2'},
  {key: 'c', value: '3'},
];

const result = arr.reduce((agg, item) => {
  agg[item.key] = item.value
  return agg
}, {})
console.log(result)
// { a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' }
```

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

Comment: While being the fancier and nicer solution, it is slower using reduce than doing a simple for loop.

Comment: Did some perf testing ... previous comment is not totally true. Its seems it can be different on each platform (e.g. with Chrome reduce is faster, in FF the loop is faster)

Answer (score 3):

simple `forEach` will do the job

```js
const arr= [
  {key: 'a', value: '1'},
  {key: 'b', value: '2'},
  {key: 'c', value: '3'},
];
const obj = {};
arr.forEach(v=>{
 obj[v.key] = v.value;
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Very easy, probably a duplicate.

```js
const arr= [
  {key: 'a', value: '1'},
  {key: 'b', value: '2'},
  {key: 'c', value: '3'},
];
const obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  obj[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value 
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function parse(input){
    return input.reduce(function(o,i){
        o[i.key] = i.value;
        return o;
    },{});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [the square brackets syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Accessing_properties) to set the properties of the new object.

```js
const arr = [
  {key: 'a', value: '1'},
  {key: 'b', value: '2'},
  {key: 'c', value: '3'},
];

const obj = {};
arr.forEach(({key, value}) => obj[key] = value);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an empty object and then create new properties on the fly, while iterating an array.

```
let obj = {};
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj[arr[i].key] = obj[i].value;
}
```